# Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the data from the POST method, it's JSON inside the list. Whenever I tried to read the JSON I'm getting an error as `ticketid = request.data.get('TicketId') AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Here, what I have tried

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def SaveUserResponse(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auditorid =request.data.get('AuditorId')
        print('SaveUserResponse auditorid---', auditorid)
        ticketid = request.data.get('TicketId')
        qid = request.data.get('QId')
        answer = request.data.get('Answer')
        sid = 0
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_SaveAuditResponse] @auditorid=%s,@ticketid=%s,@qid=%s,@answer=%s,@sid=%s',
         (auditorid,ticketid,qid,answer, sid,))
        result_st = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in result_st:
            print('sp_SaveAuditResponse', row[0])
        return Response(row[0])
    return sid
```

Payload data:

```
 [
    0: {AuditorId: 122, Agents: "", Supervisor: "", TicketId: "12111", QId: 1, Answer: "2", SID: "0",…}
    1: {AuditorId: 122, Agents: "", Supervisor: "", TicketId: "12111", QId: 2, Answer: "2", SID: "0",…}
    2: {AuditorId: 122, Agents: "", Supervisor: "", TicketId: "12111", QId: 3, Answer: "2", SID: "0",…}
    3: {AuditorId: 122, Agents: "", Supervisor: "", TicketId: "12111", QId: 4, Answer: "2", SID: "0",…}
    4: {AuditorId: 122, Agents: "", Supervisor: "", TicketId: "12111", QId: 5, Answer: "5", SID: "0",…}
    5: {AuditorId: 122, Agents: "", Supervisor: "", TicketId: "12111", QId: 6, Answer: "5", SID: "0",…}
    6: {AuditorId: 122, Agents: "", Supervisor: "", TicketId: "12111", QId: 7, Answer: "3", SID: "0",…}
    7: {AuditorId: 122, Agents: "", Supervisor: "", TicketId: "12111", QId: 8, Answer: "3", SID: "0",…}
]
```

Comment: `request.data` is a list here, so you can not use `.get`.

Comment: To clarify, you need to either specify for example `request.data[5].get('Answer')` which would equal "5" or `request.data[0].get('Answer')` which would equal "2"

Answer (score 2):

As Willem Van Onsem pointed out, your `request.data` is a list, so you cannot use `.get`. You need to access a specific dictionary from this list in order to use `.get`.

I'm not exactly sure which `TicketId` you want but if it isn't important because they are all the same, you could do:

```
request.data[0].get('TicketId')
```

If you want all Ticked IDs as list, you can use list comprehension

```
[d['TicketId'] for d in request.data]
```